# YouTube video quality list not showing 720p or higher resolution on iPhone XS Max

Tags: iphone, ios

I recently switched from `Android` to `iOS`.

*I have installed an YouTube app from App Store on my new iPhone XS Max.*

Now, when I'm playing any video on YouTube, the default max resolution quality is showing as `480p` in video quality settings of the YouTube.

Therefore, I'm not able to watch the higher resolution videos in higher resolution.

**Question :**

1. Is there any extra setting that I have to make in iOS 13 to enable watching videos at higher resolution as I'm not finding it anywhere ?

Comment: Are you on WiFi? If not, have you unchecked “Play HD on wi-fi only” in YouTube settings?

Comment: @JBallin I'm using Wifi. I have unchecked “Play HD on wi-fi only” in YouTube settings. Still Not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using Youtube App from **India**.

Keeping in mind the increased load during the lockdown, they have capped the maximum quality of streaming at 480p.

You can check out [this](https://thenextweb.com/in/2020/03/31/heres-why-youtube-videos-are-maxing-out-at-480p-in-india-right-now/) link for further confirmation.

**The workaround to resolve this issue is by using VPN.**

Comment: Then, why I'm able to play the videos in 720p from my android device ?

Comment: It must have something to do with your location settings for that device, I turn location tracking off for my iPad and can play videos in 1080p.